# LR 12.55/TruClient vusers are stuck in Init state not going to running

Tags: vugen, truclient, loadrunner

I created a TruClient Web (IE) protocol script in LR12.55, when I try to run the script with 50 users, only some would go into running state (in between 25-37) and the rest would stuck in init forever.

I tried to change the Controller -> Options-> Timeout and changed Init timeout from default 180 to 999 however it does not resolve the issue. Can anybody comment on how to resolve this????

Answer (score 2):

TruClient runs a real browser for each vuser (virtual-user), so system resource consumption is higher the API-level testing.
It is possible that 50 vusers is too much for your load-generator machine.

I'd suggest checking CPU and memory levels during the run. If either is over 80% utilization, you should split your load between multiple load-generator machines.

If resources are not fully utilized, the failures should be analyzed to determine the root cause.

Comment: we do have 3 load generators but I do receive the over 80% CPU message on all of the generators. What's the optimal CPU usage for the load generator under load?

Comment: The resources footprint in TruClient, just like any other browser, highly depends on the application.

Comment: If your application is consuming a lot of resources, you'll be able to run fewer virtual-users per load-generator. Reduce the number of Vusers to get below the 80% CPU threshold to reduce the chance of resource-related failures. You can try running a single Vuser to gain insights about the resource consumption of each one.

Answer (score 0):

To further e-Dough's excellent response, you should expect not to execute these virtual users on the same hardware as the controller.  You should expect at least three load generators to be involved, two as primary load and one as a control set.  This is in addition to the controller.

Your issue does manifest as the classical, "system out of resources" condition.  Consider the same best practices for monitoring your load generator health as you would in monitoring your application under test infrastructure.  You want to have monitors for your classical finite resource model components ( CPU, DISK, MEMORY and NETWORK) plus additional sub components, such as a breakout of System and Application under CPU, to understand where and how your system is performing.   You want to be able to eliminate false negatives on scalability where your load generators are so unhealthy that they are distorting your test results - Virtual users showing the application is slow when in fact the Virtual Users are slow because the machine in use is resource constrained.

Comment: I am running the controller on my local and we do have 3 other load generator (2 more powerful while the last one is not as powerful). What's the optimal CPU usage under load for load generator?

Comment: And where are all of the TruClient virtual users running that will not start?